# How do I link to mid-page content that's already inside a mid-page link?

Tags: html, tabs

I'm making a page that has 4 in-page tabs on it. To link to those tabs, the URL is

```
URL/#tab-1-tab; URL/#tab-2-tab etc
```

Now, in one of the tabs I want to have buttons that link to specific points on a page inside another tab, but not sure if it's actually possible to link to.
I've made the anchors on that page with

```
<a name="1"></a>
```

But I can't figure out how to link to them. I tried

```
URL/#tab-4-tab/#1 and URL/#tab-4-tab#1
```

Not sure what else to try. The links do work if I go to the tab with the anchors, then erase the tab url bit and just put in the anchor link, so instead of

```
URL/#tab-4-tab, I type in URL/#1
```

Then it jumps to the right point.

But that doesn't work if I'm on any other tab or page.

Is it possible to do this somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using tabs to switch div CSS properties like display:none / display:block then you will need some jQuery / JavaScript to switch them based of URL no differently then your jQuery that listens for the tabs "onclick" event then shows that relative div.

First step would be to obtain a JavaScript URL reader that listens for variables or hashtag-bookmarks. Here is an example of a variable reader I have used before.

http://jsfiddle.net/googabeast/hhkuj/

```
function getUrlVars() {
var vars = {};
var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
    vars[key] = value;
});
return vars;
}
//usage
var myVar = getUrlVars()["tab"];
```

That would make the URL format slightly different then your above posting, something more like "index.php?tab=2" / "index.php?tab=3" etc...

Next phase would be generate a switch based off the incoming URL variables to properly show the requested div.

Comment: This is only because CSS does not have the capability to hide/show divs based off URL commands.